# Duplicate the top element of stack Java

Tags: java, stack

I have a couple of methods in an interpreter class to carry out different operations.
One of these operations is to duplicate element of the stack (operands).
How would I go about doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand.  stack.push(stack.peek())

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Do you have push() and pop() working?

Answer (score 1):

> One of these operations is to duplicate element of the stack (operands). How would I go about doing this?

It depends on the nature of the "element", and the way you have implemented the element and stack classes.

If the elements are immutable values, then you just need to get the top element of the stack and push it again.  Or pop it and then push it twice.

If the elements are conceptually / actually mutable, then you may need to create copies of the top element before pushing it.